# Proper gitignore files for MobileFirst project

Tags: git, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing MobileFirst project targeting for iPad and Android environment.  Do we need to commit everything into git repo or are there certain folders/files that are candidates to be included in .gitignore?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the [Integrating with source control systems](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_integrating_with_source_contro.html?lang=en) user documentation topic? It lists which folders can be checked-in and which should not.

Additionally, there is the followng un-official .gitignore template that you can use: https://github.com/andrewferrier/mfp-gitignore

You do not mention which environment you are targeting, but for example for iOS you should check-in everything except for the following:

native\www
native\CordovaLib
native\Frameworks\sqlchiper

The above three are auto re-generated on build-time in MFP Studio/CLI.

Comment: thank you for the quick response and pointing out the documentation.  Regarding which environment I am targeting, I meant to say iOS and Android in my question, instead of iPad and Android.